# Can I Retrieve 'installed'=0 as fieldsForRequest using FBFriendPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am currently using FBFriendPickerViewController to create a friend picker containing all friends that have field @"installed" = 1. This works fine.

My question is, can you instead create a friend picker for inviting friends to join like:

```
self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc]
                                       initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.friendPickerController.fieldsForRequest = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"installed", nil];
[self.friendPickerController loadData];

[self.friendPickerController presentModallyFromViewController:self.navigationController
                                                         animated:YES
                                                          handler:^(FBViewController *sender, BOOL donePressed) {
                                                              if (donePressed) {
                                                                  [self inviteFriend];
                                                              }
                                                          }];



- (BOOL)friendPickerViewController:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker shouldIncludeUser:(id <FBGraphUser>)user
{
    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    BOOL isInstalled = (BOOL)[f numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[user objectForKey:@"installed"]]].intValue;

    return !isInstalled;
}
```

Currently when I request @"installed" as a fieldsForRequest, it only retrieves friends who have installed=1, but does not return all friends (which is what I want).

EDIT: I want this in order to create a friend invite dialog of friends who do not have the app installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Facebook removed this from V2 so you can only retrieve friends with installed app. You can use this instead (For my purposes, I wanted a friend invite from iOS - this fits the bill):

```
FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link name:name caption:caption description:description picture:[NSURL URLWithString:picture] clientState:nil handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share